# Why does foobar2000 reindex my NAS server on load?

Tags: nas, foobar2000

I store all my music on a network-attached storage device, rather than a drive on my computer. When I start foobar2000 it starts with nothing in the Album List - seemingly with nothing in the library. However after 10 mins or so the music all appears, which causes me to think foobar's reindexing it on every load (in fact I know it is from checking the console window).

Is there a way to get foobar to "remember" the music on there, and then resync silently on load? This is simply so I can start playing music from launch, rather than having to wait.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a static playlist (File -> New Playlist) which doesn't change until you add new files manually (Files -> Add Folder...).

If you want your playlist to be automatically updated then you need to use the media library.  Your settings should look similar to those [shown here](http://wiki.hydrogenaudio.org/index.php?title=Foobar2000:Preferences:Media_Library).

Is your NAS mounted to a windows drive letter, or are you accessing it via `\\nas\share`?

Comment: I'm using the \\nas\media style link - do you think mounting it would help? Thanks for the info though.

Comment: My guess is if you're using \\nas\media the foobar might be seeing it as a new directory each time, and not a location already seen and indexed.